# MySQL select only the newest records older than 2 days (timestamp)

Tags: mysql, join, timestamp

I have a people table, a units table, and a wellness table (described below). Basically at my work we have to check up on people, and if they haven't been seen for two days we go looking for them... What I'd like is to be able to select all records from the wellness table that are older than two days, but only the NEWEST ones (as there will probably be multiple entries per person per day, which is how I want it because with the `wellness.username` field you can tell who saw who, and when).

```
People 
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| fname      | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| lname      | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| dob        | date        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00        |                |
| license_no | varchar(24) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| date_added | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| status     | varchar(8)  | NO   |     | Allow             |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+

Units
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+ 
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| number   | varchar(3)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| resident | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| type     | varchar(16) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| wellness_id  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| people_id    | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| time_checked | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| check_type   | varchar(1)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| username     | varchar(16) | NO   |     | jmd9qs            |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

The `units` table is ugly, I know, but it will be changed soon; as it stands, `resident` references `people.id`.

Here's my Minimum Working Example, which only gives me one result even though there are multiple `people` in `wellness` that have a `time_checked` row older than 2 days. The one result I do get is more like 4-1/2 days old....

```
select w.wellness_id, p.id, p.lname, p.fname, u.number, u.type,
w.time_checked, w.check_type, w.username 
from people p 
    left join units u on p.id = u.resident
    right join wellness w on p.id = w.people_id 
    WHERE w.time_checked <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 DAY)
order by w.time_checked asc;
```

I'm trying to get the newest records that are older than two days, but only 1 per `people` that are in the `wellness` table. I join all of the other stuff because I need it for displaying records with PHP.

Sorry for my rather rambling question, hope it's clear enough!

EDIT - Sample Data:

```
+------+------+--------+---------------------+------------+----------+
| w_id | id   | number | time_checked        | check_type | username |
+------+------+--------+---------------------+------------+----------+
|  100 |    2 | 425    | 2013-08-23 21:03:00 | s          | jmd9qs   |
|  101 |    2 | 425    | 2013-08-25 05:41:01 | s          | jmd9qs   |
|   91 |    2 | 425    | 2013-08-20 19:52:23 | s          | jmd9qs   |
|   83 |    4 | 416    | 2013-08-23 20:12:29 | s          | jmd9qs   |
|   76 |    5 | 408    | 2013-08-23 20:11:21 | s          | jmd9qs   |
|   62 |    6 | 327    | 2013-08-23 20:06:13 | s          | jmd9qs   |
|   18 |    7 | 204    | 2013-08-23 19:43:58 | s          | jmd9qs   |
|   31 |    8 | 219    | 2013-08-23 19:51:11 | s          | jmd9qs   |
|   97 |    9 | 432    | 2013-08-23 20:16:39 | o          | jmd9qs   |
|   44 |   10 | 309    | 2013-08-23 19:55:45 | s          | jmd9qs   |
+------+------+--------+---------------------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired output based on it?

Comment: I can't really show you sample data because of the nature of it, but all I really NEED returned is `people.id`, `people.fname`, `people.lname`, and `unit.number` that match my criteria of a) not having been seen for 2 days and b) only one result per person

Comment: It can be fake data, nobody interested in real one. But it's needed to better understand your requirements and secondly to test a query. Otherwise we need to spend time and make it up ourselves.

Comment: This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194547/nested-select-statment-in-mysql-join

Comment: Why would you want a row for id=2? He has an entry dated 2013-08-25, you don't need to go look for him yet.

Comment: @piotrm - you're right, I don't.... it's cause I'm rambling and tired and probably shouldn't be writing any code at the moment. Editing (again) now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO `RIGHT JOIN` from `people` to `wellness` makes no sense since there shouldn't be a situation when you have a person in `wellness` but don't have that person in `people` table. But vice versa is true. You have a new person but don't have any wellness info about him or her yet.

That being said your query might look like this

```
SELECT z.wellness_id, p.id, z.time_checked, z.check_type, z.username 
  FROM people p JOIN units u
    ON p.id = u.resident  LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT w.*
    FROM
  (
    SELECT people_id, MAX(time_checked) time_checked
      FROM wellness
     GROUP BY people_id
  ) q JOIN wellness w 
      ON q.people_id = w.people_id
     AND q.time_checked = w.time_checked
) z 
    ON p.id = z.people_id
 WHERE COALESCE(time_checked, 0) < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85cdc/6)** demo

Comment: To be completely honest I'm not 100% on joins yet, I just know I was using it because it didn't throw any `NULL` values at me. Your query did, however, but I couldn't tell you why

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but I replaced the `right join` with a `left join` and the results remained the same.

Comment: @jmd9qs sqlfiddle example that I provided models a situation when you have a person in people table but don't have wellness checking information about him/her (at least yet). Now according to your requirements and common sense these records should be in the resultset since nobody checked on those people yet. In my example those are people with id 1 and 3. If you change  left join to inner join you won't see these records.

Comment: You are correct, thanks for your input. I never mentioned it, but I had planned ahead for that and any time a person is added into `people`, they also get added into `wellness`, which is probably why it confused me.

Comment: I'll use yours as the answer as I never gave that caveat. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the query that gets what I want:

```
select p.id, u.number,
    w.time_checked, w.check_type, w.username 
    from people p inner join units u on p.id = u.resident
    left join wellness w on p.id = w.people_id 
    left outer join wellness as w2 ON w.people_id = w2.people_id
    and w.time_checked < w2.time_checked
    where w2.people_id is null and w.time_checked  < (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY)
order by w.time_checked asc
```

Comment: Thanks to @Stephen O'Flynn!