# SQL Join Table vs. Select

Tags: sql, join

I have inherited some legacy SQL code with the following snippet (I've anonymized for simplicity sake).

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dim_abc (user_id int)

CREATE TABLE dim_foo AS
SELECT user_id,
       ...
FROM my_table a
JOIN (SELECT * FROM dim_abc) b
ON (a.user_id = b.user_id)
```

Instead of...

```
FROM my_table a
JOIN dim_abc b
ON (a.user_id = b.user_id)
```

Any idea why the previous developer would have done the SELECT within the JOIN?

** The code is Hive.

Comment: Look at the differnce of the 2 statements. Do they generate different tables? Only I can think of is that be subselect might supress parameters of the table definition the dev did not want to inherit in the new table

Comment: the ellipsis confuses things a bit.  Its hard to tell if they are doing recursion or if those are two different statements separated by the ellipsis.  Could you post the whole code?

Comment: Good SO article addressing this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194547/nested-select-statment-in-mysql-join

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle?

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name - This is Hive.

Comment: paqogomez - I cannot post the whole code.  There should not be any recursion inherent from the SQL statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version without the subselect is better for a variety of reasons.  Some databases (you don't mention the database) would lose the ability to use the indexes on `dim_abc` because of the subquery.

That is not your question, though.  My best guess is that the code started out more complicated.  What is now `dim_abc` might have required extra logic at one point in time.  As the code was simplified, the end result was a useless subquery in the `from` clause.  This is just a guess, but it offers one plausible scenario.

Comment: Are there performance advantages from NOT using the subselect?

Comment: They ought to be equivalent although it's possible that the longer version fakes out the parser/optimizer which doesn't recognize it as a base table. Something like that could go either way and might have even been the intention. I know nothing about Hive and would tend to agree with Gordon though.

Comment: @user2715877 . . . Most databases will generate the same execution plan for the two queries.  However, MySQL (and related DBs) will materialize the subquery, causing a performance problem.  However, this is not MySQL, because another limitation is that subselects are not allowed in the `from` clause for a view.